# How to set element in array to null in C program

Tags: c, arrays, unix, null, element

I am writing a C program in Unix and cannot figure out how to set an array element to NULL. I need to be able to do this to remove multiple characters from a string.

Comment: Show some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean you want to shorten the string by adding in the NULL character at some location?

Just assign '\0' to it.

Comment: The null byte is a string *terminator* - if you want to remove characters, you need to move the following characters left, not overwrite the "bad" characters with null.

Comment: @adam - Also being polite to accept answers, you are more likely to get more help in the future.

Comment: Why does this question has a Unix tag on it?

Answer (score 7):

You can't assign `null` to specific char array index as value represented by that index is char instead of pointer. But if you need to remove specific character from given string, you can implement this as follows

```
void removeChar(char *str, char garbage) {

    char *src, *dst;
    for (src = dst = str; *src != '\0'; src++) {
        *dst = *src;
        if (*dst != garbage) dst++;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
}
```

Test Program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char* str = malloc(strlen("abcdef")+1);
    strcpy(str, "abcdbbbef");
    removeChar(str, 'b');
    printf("%s", str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
acdef
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I'm afraid not necessarily appropriate to the question.

Comment: That has really, really nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: I'm afraid `char array[10];` wouldn't just be initialised to a bunch of zeros. In fact, when you don't initialise a variable, but just declare it like you did, values previously stored in memory would usually be assigned to it. You're just reserving memory for your variable, but not "cleaning" it, hence what was in there is still there and it is the current value for your variable. It is in fact good practice not to initialise variables like this: `char string[size];` but instead like this: `char string[size] = "";`.

Comment: why are you only talking about initialization ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `char[]`, you can zero-out individual elements using this:

```
char arr[10] = "foo";
arr[1] = '\0';
```

Note that this isn't the same as assigning `NULL`, since `arr[1]` is a `char` and not a pointer, you can't assign `NULL` to it.

That said, that probably won't do what you think it will. The above example will produce the string `f`, not `fo` as you seem to expect.

If you want to remove characters from a string, you have to shift the contents of the string to the left (including the null terminator) using `memmove` and some pointer arithmetic:

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int removechars(char *str, size_t pos, size_t cnt) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (pos + cnt > len)
        return -1;

    memmove(str + pos, str + pos + cnt, len - pos - cnt + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
char str[12] = "hello world";
if (removechars(str, 5, 4) == 0)  /* remove 4 chars starting at str[5] */
    printf("%s\n", str);          /* hellold */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about an array of pointers (say `char **`), you'd just say `array[element] = NULL;`.  But it sounds as though you really want to just truncate a string (`char *`), in which case you'd actually want to write `string[index] = '\0'`, where `\0` is the null byte.  But, as far as I know, `0`, `'\0'`, and `NULL` are all equivalent and equal to 0 (please correct me if I'm wrong).  Of course, for clarity, you should use `0` for numbers, `'\0'` for chars and strings, and `NULL` for pointers.

Comment: `NULL` is often `(void*)0`, that would elicit an "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" warning then. And on the few platforms where a `NULL` pointer is not all-bits-0, it could produce the wrong result.